# Attempting Ant build with Weblogic 10.3 Dependency

Tags: ant, build, ivy, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I'm a CM and am responsible for our Continuous build process, and helping the developers define and use the builds correctly. I try to set things up in such a way that the developer merely has to download the module from the Source control system, and type in `ant` or `maven` and have everything just work.

In Ant projects, I either use `ivy` or have a `lib` directory that contains the required third party jar files. This helps me to clearly define all the dependencies and makes it easy for the developers to get the module to build on their system. Yes, there is some dependency on the right JDK version, and somewhat on the right Ant version, but even these are a bit flexible. Besides Ecipse and Jenkins/Hudson allow you to define the exact JDK and Ant versions you want to use.

The problem is this one project that's dependent upon Weblogic 10.3 (aka 11g). Before Weblogic 10, you could pretty much get away with using just the weblogic.jar file and maybe one or two other jars. Starting with Weblogic 10, the jars are now "modularized".

When I do a build, I still simply include `weblogic.jar` in my classpath. However, `weblogic.jar`, in its `MANIFEST.MF` file contains references to the `..\..\..\modules\features` directory (which is actually the parent directory that contains Weblogic 10.3!). In here are jars that contain no classpaths, but themselves have a Classpath embedded in their `MANIFEST.MF` that points to other jars. These in turn can refer to other jars.

I figure I have one of these choices:

1. Include the entire 10,900 file, 700Mb Weblogic in my source repository for each module.
2. Somehow download Weblogic using either Maven or Ivy as a single tarball. Untar the file, then do my build.
3. Tell the developers that they must download Weblogic 10.3 and then modify the build process to point to where they installed Weblogic 10.3.

None of these options really appeal to me right now.

---

## UPDATE

As others pointed out, I could try to find the various jars, and I did exactly that with Weblogic 9.x and earlier versions. For example, a simple shell script:

```
find $WEBLOGIC_HOME -name "*.jar" | while read jar
do
   echo "JAR NAME = jar"
   jar tvf $jar
done | less
```

would display the content of all Weblogic JARs on my terminal. If I find in a build that `javax.servlet.ServletException` class is missing, I could search for `javax\servlet\ServletException.class`, then go back up searching for the `JAR NAME =` and find the name of the jar.

However, in Weblogic 10, I found that I depended upon `javax.servlet.ServletException`, and traced it back to the `C:\bea\modules\javax.servlet_1.0.0.0.0.jar` which isn't even in my `$WEBLOGIC_HOME` directory. This is because `C:\bea\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar` contains a classpath to `..\..\..\modules\features\somejar.jar`. And `somejar.jar` doesn't contain any classes. Instead it contains a reference to another jar in its classpath, which then refers to the `javax.servlet_1.0.0.0.0.jar`.

So, I now have to add in four more jars, one of which contains no classes, and if I want to emulate the structure of Weblogic, I have to have the following files in my `lib` directory:

- `weblogic.lib\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar`
- `weblogic.lib\modules\features\somejar.jar`
- `weblogic.lib\modules\someOtherJar.jar`
- `weblogic.lib\modules\javax.servlet_1.0.0.0.0.jar`

Okay, that only took about 2 hours to resolve. One dependency issue down, 43 more to go.

As you can see, this may take days, even weeks to complete, and end up with dozens of jars in my ...uh... *minimal* Weblogic 10 module. In the end, this *minimal* module may not be all that much smaller.

Does anyone know of maybe some documentation that allows me to quickly determine where these dependencies exist, or a way of building a dependency tree, so that when I need the classpath com.bea.weblogic.foo.bar.barfoo, I can quickly see that I need these 7 or 8 jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up. I simply installed Weblogic 10 and checked in my `build.xml` that `$WEBLOGIC_HOME` is set.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you won't need the whole 700MB package to build. So you could (yes, that's some work to do) build your own "weblogic-ivy" file, that describes the mininmal jar-set for build and test.
Publish that file to your company repo and use it in your dependency conf and you and your developers can just work with the minimal conf which shouldn't be much larger than other app-server-client packages.

Comment: We use conceptually similar approach (minus Ivy - jars in source repository) for our builds, which works well. You just have to go through the effort of determining which jars are required. I am willing to wager that it will be a very small subset on top of the main weblogic.jar file. You will, of course, need an actually install to run your unit tests, but it is still useful to be able to build without having a WLS install.

Comment: Calinski The problem is knowing WHICH of those 700Mb of file are the ones we need. With Weblogic 9.x, it was weblogic.jar and maybe two or three others. I could easily figure that out with a little sleuthing. However, this is proving to be much more complex.